# cell validation and arrays

Tags: arrays, validation, vba, element

two questions, first can you remind me how to polulate a multidimensional array when assigning it? I always do it with for loop and how to staticly do it seems to escape me?

But what I am really looking to do is to use the array to validate cells contents. however in the example below I want to use only the first element in the 2nd dimension.

ie
0,0
1,0
2,0
3,0
4,0

Is there any way to update the .Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:=Join(ary, ",") line so it only returns these 5 values from a 5 by 4 array?

Cheeers

aaron

```
Sub test()


Dim ary As Variant
ReDim ary(5,4)


ary = Array("Value1", "Value2", "Value3", "test", "test2", "test3", "test4")

With ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:=Join(ary, ",")
    .IgnoreBlank = False
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you need a multi-dimensional array here? If you're actually filling it from a range, then you could just give the range a name and then use that name in the validation.

Comment: the array holds data in the folling format  0,0 = description, 0,1 = start postition, 0,2 = end postition. I only want the cells validated on the description. The actulay array is populated at run time. and is x by 3 in size. I know i could pull out the descriptions in to a seperate array, but this seems iniffecnet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resizing of a 2D array to 1D is quick

The code below populates your 5*4 array with sample data, a second loop then extracts only the first dimension to a new 1D array withe the same row length as your initial array

```
Sub test()

    Dim ary As Variant
    Dim X As Variant
    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim lngCol As Long

    ReDim ary(1 To 5, 1 To 4)
    ReDim X(1 To UBound(ary, 1))

    For lngRow = 1 To UBound(ary, 1)
        For lngCol = 1 To UBound(ary, 2)
            ary(lngRow, lngCol) = "I am row " & lngRow & "  and dimension " & lngCol
        Next
    Next

    For lngRow = 1 To UBound(ary, 1)
    X(lngRow) = ary(lngRow, 1)
    Next

    With ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:=Join(X, ",")
        .IgnoreBlank = False
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: As I said i have no trouble extracing to a 1d array, I wanted to know if I can achive the above with out having to take this step.

Comment: I don't believe so, I have never seen a shortcut on the 2D to 1D method. That said looping arrays is very efficient time wise even if it feels like inefficient coding. I thought that my approach above may be of some use depending on your existing style, if not thats fine to ignore it. Cheers.

Comment: I will bow to your expertise, I quite shocked to see that you cant simple pull out the values of a single a row/coloum from an array. Ie lock all dimensions aprat from one. I supose this is some thing you do in networking quite a lot, applying masks to restrict what can and can't change. What has helped in your code a lot is the use of UBound on multi dimenon arrays. As this is somethign I do need to use :) Thanks for the help and the comments.